# What is dependency path of css modules in webpack

Tags: webpack, postcss

Why CSS Modules work in `webpack`?

- `webpack` includes `postcss`
- `postcss` includes `react-css-modules`
- `react-css-modules` handles css modules

Am I right? There is no original [css modules lib](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)?

The dependency path is extremely unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [github css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) is just a specification.

- `webpack` uses `css-loader`
- `css-loader` [uses](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/master/package.json#L47-L51=) `postcss-modules` packages
- `postcss-modules` handles css modules